# What is an Alembic Cache and can it be converted to fbx or dae?

Tags: alembic

Can anyone help me understand what an alembic cache is? and can I convert it to any other format like fbx or dae? I am specifically looking to bring it on the web and play the animation online essentially .

Comment: Roughly said, it's a mesh sequence, so every frame in cache is like a new mesh. I am not sure Blender's FBX/Collada alows to export vertex animation. But if your cache represents consistent geometry, the best you can do is to convert it to point cache - pc2/mdd.

Comment: @Ray Mairlot thank you ill look into it